# Can I load an earlier save, complete quests & grab stuff, and then go back to my latest time?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I broke the Nightingale quest line, and was wondering if can I go back to an old save file, do what I need to do, then just load my latest save?

Will I still have the stuff I got in the load file?

Answer (score 8):

No, you can't. A save game saves your current state. That means, your completed quests, your inventory, stuff you dropped in the world and NPC you killed. So if you load an older save, complete the Nightingale Quest there and then load your original save file again, then you won't have anything in that save file that you did previously in another one.

However, if you are on PC, you can reset the the Quest "[Darkness Returns](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Darkness_Returns)" via [Console Commands](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console):

```
resetquest TG09
```

and continue your current save game. However, make a backup of your save game first since this can mess up things.

Answer (score 4):

You can understand save files as being alternate timelines. Each save you create creates a different timeline, and if you change something on that timeline/save file, it doesn't change anything on the other save file/timeline.